# Cannot connect to database using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, xml, database, hibernate

I am working on a sample Hibernate+MySQL application taken from [here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-hello-world-tutorial-for-beginners-with-eclipse-and-mysql). I am not able to connect to the database when I try to run the program. [Here](https://pastebin.com/GtUVxmWj) is the stack trace.

The contents of hibernate.cfg.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>       
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">helloWORLD12</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="net.codejava.hibernate.Book" />

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Where am I going wrong? I have checked that the database username and password is correct.

Comment: The NullPointerException is coming from your `BookManager.java setup()` line 29. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: add <property name="hbmdl.auto">create-drop</property> and <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  recheck

Comment: It seems some mysql-connector jar version related issues. Are you using same mysql database version and java version?

Comment: @MohammadRezaAlagheband I tried doing that...still the same issue persists.

Comment: @Karthik I am using the following external libraries: https://imgur.com/a/7bG89Sa

Comment: @pikaraider can you please add full code for BookManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you're using an older version of the MySQL driver. You should try using the newest version.

To get the newest version, you can [check](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)

I think Suddenly we should not go to higher version as it causes more issues. I have just updated with the latest 5.1.x version.  You can download it here or add this to your pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.47</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I used the newest version of MySQL driver. Now I am getting the following error trace: https://pastebin.com/N7y3iAti

I am calling setup(), followed by create(), and then delete() in the main function of BookManager.java. Also, I have created the table using MySQL client. Where am I going wrong now?

Comment: I think Suddenly we should not go to higher version as it causes more issue. I have just updated with the latest 5.1.x version. I have updated my answer

Comment: Updating the version to 5.1.47 worked for me. Thanks @Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

Based on stack trace issue is with server which is not reachable it seems.

1. Check if server is up. If possible use client to connect and check if it is up.
2. Restart mysql server once and check port as well if it is correct.

You configuration looks fine and it should work. Run a test on server and port to check you are using correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">helloWORLD12</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```